# UnityでBuild Settingsに変更を加えたことを検出するコールバック関数はありますか？

Tags: unity3d, build

Unity3Dで、
Build Settingsに変更を加えたことを検出するようなコールバックが存在するのであれば、教えていただけますでしょうか。
存在しないのであれば、どのように実装するのか教えて頂きたいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

現在サポートされているのは、ターゲットプラットフォームを変更したことだけのようです。
Build Settingsの個々の内容を変更したことの検出・通知は無いようです。

[第13章　さまざまなイベントのコールバック](https://anchan828.github.io/editor-manual/web/callbacks.html)
[13.6　EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTargetChanged](https://anchan828.github.io/editor-manual/web/callbacks.html#h13-6)

> Build Settings ウィンドウや EditorUserBuildSettings.SwitchActiveBuildTarget によって、プラットフォームが変更された時に呼び出されるコールバックです。プラットフォームごとに異なる設定、例えば BundleIdentifier の変更や、StreamingAssets や Resources フォルダーの中身の変更などで活用できます。

設定するのは、こちらの変数にコールバックを登録する形でしょう。
[EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTargetChanged](https://docs.unity3d.com/jp/460/ScriptReference/EditorUserBuildSettings-activeBuildTargetChanged.html)

> public static var activeBuildTargetChanged: Action;
>
> Description
>   SwitchActiveBuildTargetでプラットフォームが変更された直後に呼び出されるコールバックを設定します
>
> See Also: System.Action.

関連メソッドはこれですね。
[EditorUserBuildSettings.SwitchActiveBuildTarget](https://docs.unity3d.com/jp/460/ScriptReference/EditorUserBuildSettings.SwitchActiveBuildTarget.html)

> public static function SwitchActiveBuildTarget(target: BuildTarget): bool;
>
> Description
>   ビルドターゲットを変更します
>
> 注意: このメソッドは バッチモード でエディタを起動している時に使用することは出来ません。

ターゲットプラットフォームを変更以外の細かいことを知りたいのなら、無理やりですが、
このコールバックを登録するというのも出来るのではないでしょうか。
[13.13　EditorApplication.globalEventHandler](https://anchan828.github.io/editor-manual/web/callbacks.html#h13-13)

> Unity エディター全体でなんらかのイベントが実行された時に実行されるコールバックです。これは正式には公開されていませんが、なんらかのキーイベントやマウス位置など把握したい時に使用すると便利です
>   下記コードは、globalEventHandler を使いやすくしたラッパークラスです。
>   　　注）図は省略。
>   図13.9: 適当なところでキーを押すとログが表示されていく
>   　　注）コードは省略
>   ただし、ゲームビューや、ほかの一部のウィンドウ上では動作しないので注意してください。

少し戻って、こんな記述もあるようです。こちらの方が独自コールバック実装に向いていますか。
[13.11　EditorApplication.update](https://anchan828.github.io/editor-manual/web/callbacks.html#h13-13)

> Unity エディターの更新タイミングで呼び出されるコールバックです。エディターにも MonoBehaviour の Update のような一定の更新タイミングがあります。呼び出されるのは約 200回/秒 となり、描画系処理の前に実行されます。*4
>   [*4] 200回/秒実行されるのはバグとの報告があります。ドキュメントでは 100回/秒と記載されています。
>   例えば WWW の通信でも使用できます。
>   　　注）コードは省略
>   このほかにも**独自のコールバックを実装するときにも使用できます。**
>   下記コードは、フォーカスしている EditorWindow が変更するごとに呼び出されるコールバックを作成します。
>   　　**注）コードは省略しますが、これが実装例：紹介先を参照のこと**

上記設定用変数はこれでしょう。
[EditorApplication.update](https://docs.unity3d.com/jp/460/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-update.html)

> public static var update: CallbackFunction;
>
> Description
>   UnityEditorで更新処理を行うためのデリゲート
>
> おおよそ100回/秒のタイミングで呼び出されるコールバックをこのデリゲートに追加します。 See Also: EditorApplication.CallbackFunction.

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。シーンの追加・削除を検出したいと思っているところです。やっぱり独自のコールバックを実装する必要がありそうですね。

Comment: シーンの追加・削除だと、これ [13.7 EditorApplication.hierarchyWindowChanged と projectWindowChanged](https://anchan828.github.io/editor-manual/web/callbacks.html#h13-7) が使えるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class SceneListChangedMonitor : MonoBehaviour
{
    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    static void Initialize()
    {
        Debug.Log("シーンリスト監視開始");
        EditorBuildSettings.sceneListChanged += () =>
        {
            //シーン一覧からシーン名と状態を取得
            foreach(var scene in EditorBuildSettings.scenes)
            {
                Debug.Log($"Scene = {scene.path} is {scene.enabled}");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Build Settingsのシーン一覧に変更があったときにコンソールログにシーン一覧が出力されるコードはこのように実装されるそうです。